# how to use WhereIn with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I'm working on email web application. I just started playing with laravel and am creating my first project on it. So far so good but just stuck with query binding. I'm unable to update my database.
What I am doing wrong??
Any help would highly be appreciated.
Thanks

```
//update
public function update($id)
{
    if(Request::ajax())
    {
        $input=Input::get('fav');
        if($input!=null){
        $fav=Input::get('fav');
        DB::table('email')
        ->where('Id', $id)
        ->update(array('favorite' => $fav));//This query works fine
        }else{
         $chkbox_id=array_map('intval', explode(',', $id));//array(11) {  [0]=>  int(0)  [1]=>  int(12)  [2]=>  int(24)  [3]=>  int(26)  [4]=>  int(27)  [5]=>  int(28)  [6]=>  int(29)  [7]=>  int(30)  [8]=>  int(31)  [9]=>  int(32)  [10]=>  int(33)}
             DB::table('email')->whereIn('Id',$chkbox_id)->update(array('status'=>'unread'));//
             dd(DB::getQueryLog());// array(3) {    ["query"]=>  string(79)
            "update `email` set `status` = ? where `Id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"   
            ["bindings"]=>    array(12) {[0]=>string(6) "unread"  [1]=>int(0) 
            [2]=>int(12) [3]=>int(24) [4]=>int(26) [5]=>int(27) [6]=> int(28)
            [7]=>int(29) [8]=>int(30) [9]=>int(31) [10]=>int(32)   [11]=>int(33)}
            ["time"]=>    float(69.1)  
              }
            }   
        }
    }
```

**Update**

The code works fine no issues with that!

You are free to use!

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv   When I hard code the data the that works fine why is to so??

Comment: How does `$id` look like if you are doing `$chkbox_id=array_map('intval', explode(',', $id));` on it?

Comment: Am passing as parameter via ajax call ,12,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33

Comment: And what does `var_dump($chkbox_id)` output?

Comment: I had shown that code in above example in comment on this line
         $chkbox_id=array_map('intval', explode(',', $id));//array(11) {  [0]=>  int(0)

Comment: So the query executes (you got debug output on it using `getQueryLog`). What's the issue then? (Absolutely no difference between `array(1,22,25,26,27)` and `$chkbox_id`, except the actual values obviously)

Comment: That's the question why laravel doesn't let me insert the actual data rather hard coded values....!!

Comment: (1) You are not executing any insert queryes and (2) the _update_ query executes, I don't see any issue with this code, it does what it was written to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help n sorry for the question I just checked my db and tried some more time and it actually started working....!! Sorry again